# How to cause CXF to generate a SecurityTokenReference in a SOAP Security header?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, cxf, wss4j

I'm having an issue with cxf not generating the proper Soap Security block for authenticating using SAML 1.1. I've been working on this for a few days, and I'm fairly new to this technology. I'd appreciate any help:

I'm connecting to a service that uses SAML 1.1 tokens, and I can successfully connect and retrieve a saml token from the authentication service.  But, I get authentication errors from the server when I make a subsequent service call.  I obtained an example soap request from the host (who appears to be using weblogic) to compare with my cxf output, and found a difference:

The working example has a `wsse:SecurityTokenReference` element as a direct child of the `wsse:Security` element.  In other words, in the envelope the path is: `/env:Header/wsse:Security/wsse:SecurityTokenReference`.

That `SecurityTokenReference` contains a `KeyIdentifier` element which points at the saml's `SAMLAssertionID`.  Later, in the `dsig:Signature` block, there's a `dsig:Reference URI` pointing to the `SecurityTokenReference`.

I'm supposedly using the same Policy document as the service provider, but cxf isn't producing that child element.  I've found from others' legacy code in the organization that they took to writing the entire security header themselves, and after going through the `PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptor`, I think I could use an Aspect to write out the STR element directly in the `AssymetricBindingHandler.handleBinding()` call. But that seems senseless because the element is part of the WS-Security 1.0 spec and xsd, so presumably wss4j & cxf should be able to generate it.

I thought maybe this output would be triggered by something in the Policy, and after going through several WS-* spec documents I came across the `sp:RequireKeyIdentifierReference` tag, but placing that in my own test version of the policy after the `sp:WssSAMLV11Token10` elements had no effect.

Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What version of CXF are you using? It's possible that this is a bug that has been fixed, so please try with an up-to-date version. If that still doesn't work, drop an email to the CXF users mailing list including the policy of the service, and I'll take a look.

Comment: Hi, we're using version 3.1.7 so it's fairly new, and I didn't see anything in the newer release notes about this.  Thanks for the reply, I'll send something to the users group.